# What animal am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'm black as the night, but I hide it well
>   I'm the fastest around, as my fleeing victims can tell
>   My brothers and sisters live everywhere on earth
>   Except on the Poles, there we give no birth
>
> I live on one continent only, with an A it starts
>   It lies in the south, on almost all geographic *cards*
>   Our species survived the massive extinction, a long time ago
>   My ancestors and dinosaurs could have been friends, for all I know

So, what animal am I?

Hint:

> See my comment on *@Thrax*' answer. (S)he had two of the lines correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you a:

> Black Mamba

I'm black as the night, but I hide it well

> Self explanatory

I'm the fastest around, as my fleeing victims can tell

> Fastest land snake around

My brothers and sisters live everywhere on earth

Except on the arctic, there we give no birth

> Snakes live in most continents(?) but not in the arctic

I live on one continent only, with an A it starts

It lies in the south, on almost all geographic cards

> Black mambas are only found in Africa

Our species survived the massive extinction, a long time ago

My ancestors and dinosaurs could have been friends, for all I know

> Snakes are thought to have been around since the dinosaurs

Comment: Everything is correct! :) You only forgot the first line of the rhyme though `"I'm black as the night, but I hide it well"`, but I think it's obvious now.

Comment: Oops, my bad! Credit to @Thrax for the Africa part though.

Comment: Africa is (mostly) in the south regardless of which map projection you use.  Some maps place south on the top, but it's still south.

Comment: @Luke4792 Actually, it's still not correct. :) But since you've got everything else correct I'm just gonna spoil it: `"I'm black as the night, but I hide it well"` -> Black Mambas are brown or grey on the outside, and only black on the inside of their mouth (hence the `but I hide it well`, since it's not always visible). They got their name from the black in their mouth.

Comment: Ah, feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: I'd argue about where they live - I personally know two keepers of them in the UK... :)

Comment: There aren't any snakes in Antarctica either, so the answers which propose birds fit that clue much better. (@KevinCruijssen)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Which clue are you talking about now? `"Except on the arctic, there we give no birth"` or `"I live on one continent only, with an A it starts"`? In case of the second, it's opposite of your comment ("There aren't any snakes in Antarctica"), so I'm a bit confused. The line state the one continent where the Black Mamba *does* live (Africa), not doesn't (Antarctica among others).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, "*My brothers and sisters live everywhere on earth except on the arctic*"

Comment: @PeterTaylor Snakes can be found anywhere on earth, except on the North or South Poles. I agree that the answers with the birds were also pretty well-thought-out, but `"My brothers and sisters live everywhere on earth except on the arctic"` fits the description of snakes just as well, if not better. [There are more birds than just Penguins that live on Antarctica.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_birds_of_Antarctica)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, my point is that the Arctic only covers the North: the South is the Antarctic, and it requires a distorted interpretation of the clue for snakes to fit.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ah, now I understand. Sorry, I didn't knew the Arctic covers just the north. When I made the question I thought Arctic covered both poles. My bad; English isn't my native language. I've edited the question to Poles instead. Thanks for correcting me, and sorry for the confusing this may have caused..

Answer (score 4):

Could you be :

> Panthers

I'm black as the night, but I hide it well :

> Panthers are black predators able to hide in the savannah

I'm the fastest around, as my fleeing victims can tell

> While the fastest are cheetah, panthers can run really fast too!

My brothers and sisters live everywhere on earth

> Cats can be found about anywhere

Except on the arctic, there we give no birth

> Except there, I guess...

I live on one continent only, with an A it starts

> Panthers live in Africa

It lies in the south, on almost all geographic cards

> Most country place Africa in the south, except for Australia for example

Our species survived the massive extinction, a long time ago
My ancestors and dinosaurs could have been friends, for all I know

> Could be a long reach, but sabre-toothed tigers are feline who lived at the same time as the dinosaurs

Comment: Again +1, but also not correct. As a hint I will say that your answer for `"I live on one continent only, with an A it starts"` and `"It lies in the south, on almost all geographic cards"` are correct though.

Answer (score 3):

My answer :

> Penguin

I'm black as the night, but I hide it well

> black in the back, it is hidden by the white on the face

I'm the fastest around, as my fleeing victims can tell

> swim fast and catch fish

My brothers and sisters live everywhere on earth

Except on the arctic, there we give no birth

> brothers and sisters are the birds (which do not live in Artic ?)

I live on one continent only, with an A it starts

It lies in the south, on almost all geographic cards

> Antartica

Comment: Snowy owls live in the arctic regions (as do other birds). Your bird itself only lives in the southern hemisphere - unless one includes captivity - so I don't think it will fit there either

Comment: +1 Although it is not correct. :) Also, you've excluded the last two lines of the rhyme.

Comment: I have excluded the two last lines because I don't how long Penguins have been existing ;)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1211/ would support the last 2 lines

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

> Emu

I'm black as the night, but I hide it well

> All Emu feathers are [black tipped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emu#Description) but how dark they actually look varies by the climate.

I'm the fastest around, as my fleeing victims can tell

> They run at [speeds around 30 mph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emu#Description)

My brothers and sisters live everywhere on earth

> Other flightless birds, especially [Ostriches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struthio) exist all over the Southern and some of the Northern hemisphere

Except on the arctic, there we give no birth

> Emu and other flightless birds tend to be poor survivors under Artic conditions so I have found no record of any living, wild, in those regions

I live on one continent only, with an A it starts
It lies in the south, on almost all geographic cards

> Emu's are native to Australia

Our species survived the massive extinction, a long time ago
My ancestors and dinosaurs could have been friends, for all I know

> Though there is some debate I have seen flightless birds as beginning in the Cretaceous Period - which means that they could have existed with dinosaurs. This also puts them at about 65 million years ago so [they also could have survived the last mass extinction or at least a mass extinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinction_event#Patterns_in_frequency)

Comment: +1 Again a well-thought-out answer, but also not the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are

> Some kind of insect, eg. a black widow ([Latrodectus mactans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latrodectus_mactans))

You are black, you live in

> America, mostly South

Your family...

> ie. other spiders,

...live on every continent, except polar regions.

You are fast because of

> poison (it kills quickly)

(But I can't explain "mass extinction")

Comment: Spiders are not insects.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a:

> Ostrich

I'm black as the night, but I hide it well

> Black skin covered by feather

I'm the fastest around, as my fleeing victims can tell

> Fastest birds on land.

My brothers and sisters live everywhere on earth
Except on the arctic, there we give no birth

> Birds live in most continents but not in the Arctic

I live on one continent only, with an A it starts
It lies in the south, on almost all geographic cards

> Africa

Our species survived the massive extinction, a long time ago
My ancestors and dinosaurs could have been friends, for all I know

> Brids are thought to have been around since the dinosaurs